# GET URL gives me a net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, how do i get rid of this error in my console?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Im working with react and express and im trying to get data from an API but
i keep getting the following error:

*"GET https://localhost:8080/devices/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"*

im using the following code in my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong ?

Comment: What gives you this error?! The Browser, node? You server does not server requests over https. Use http.

Comment: @marc the browser (the console in the browser)

Comment: As mentioned, you dont server your site over https. Thats the reason your browser cant establish a TLS/SSL connection with your server. Use "http" for all URLs and it should work

Comment: Just change to `http://localhost:8080/devices` and it should work.

This error is because you're don't have the correct settings for TLS/SSL cert for `https`